# Can ActionDispatch::Session::SessionRestoreError be rescued?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Occasionally breaking changes cause ActionDispatch::Session::SessionRestoreError exceptions. It would be great to be able to do something like this to automatically clear invalid sessions:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionDispatch::Session::SessionRestoreError do |exception|
    reset_session
    redirect_to :home
  end
end
```

This doesn't work -- I'm assuming because the exception is happening at the lower ActionDispatch layer. Is there a way to recover from these errors?

Comment: I think sessions are checked in a middleware, this is where you should look

Comment: Weird issue when using InheritedResources for your Controllers, being in a namespace and calling a resource class inside another namespace causes this error. instead of `defaults resource_class: Plus::Whatever` I had to use `defaults resource_class: ::Plus::Whatever`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can. The robust solution is following:

1. Open `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`
2. Change the value for `YourApp::Application.config.secret_token`, e.g. by replacing the last char to something else
3. Restart the Rails server

I know it doesn't directly solve the problem in question and automating it is relatively hard and not a very good idea (autorewriting app config), but it could be an (expensive) option.

I experienced it with large chunks being written to a session so you can also make sure to check your session against any extensive data storage and swop it to the database.

Comment: Excellent -- haven't had this issue for quite a while, but it's good to know there's something that can be done, even if it's manual.